# Agrupando query por data

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma consulta com C#, mas estou com um problema para realizar a mesma. Preciso agrupar por data.

Código:

```
public void BuscarVendaDeProdurtos_Saidas()
{
    var data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateINI_Saida.Text);
    var data2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFINI_Saida.Text);
    var cod = Convert.ToInt64(textBox8.Text);

    var pesquisa = from p in dc.ITEMVENDA
    orderby p.CD_PRODUTO descending
    where p.CD_PRODUTO == cod && p.Data_Venda >= data1 && p.Data_Venda <= data2
    select new
    {

        p.NM_PROD,
        p.Data_Venda,
        p.QT_PRODV,
    };

    dataGridView2.DataSource = pesquisa.ToList();

    Soma = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView2.Rows)
    Soma += Convert.ToDecimal(dr.Cells[2].Value);
    textBox12.Text = Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:n}", Soma));
}
```

Essa pesquisa retorna isso:

```
Data Produto      Qt
20/10/2017……………….  3
20/10/2017 …………….. 1
```

Preciso de algo assim:

```
Data Produto     Qt
20/10/2017………………. 4
```

Uma única data já com as suas quantidades somada.

Comment: Não entendo de c#, então peço desculpas se falar bobagem, mas esses dados estão vindo de um banco? Por que não usar SQL direto, tipo `select data, count(*) from tabela group by data order by data`?

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer o group by com uma data formatada com dd/mm/yyyy

```
public void BuscarVendaDeProdurtos_Saidas()
{
    var data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateINI_Saida.Text);
    var data2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFINI_Saida.Text);
    var cod = Convert.ToInt64(textBox8.Text);

    var pesquisa = from p in dc.ITEMVENDA
    orderby p.CD_PRODUTO descending
    where p.CD_PRODUTO == cod && p.Data_Venda >= data1 && p.Data_Venda <= data2
    select new
    {

        p.NM_PROD,
        p.Data_Venda,
        p.QT_PRODV,
    };

    dataGridView2.DataSource = pesquisa // .ToList() 
    //.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Data_Venda, "dd/MM/yyyy", null))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Data_Venda.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"))
        .ToList();
    ;

    Soma = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView2.Rows)
    Soma += Convert.ToDecimal(dr.Cells[2].Value);
    textBox12.Text = Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:n}", Soma));
}
```

Comment: ola amigo o método que você explicou  me retorna o seguinte erro:O LINQ to Entidades não reconhece o método 'System.DateTime ParseExact (System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)', e esse método não pode ser traduzido para uma expressão de loja. '

Comment: use o ToList() ... deixei comentado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o GroupBy do linq para agrupar.

Não sei qual o nome dos atributos do seu objeto mas tente trocar essa linha:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = pesquisa.ToList();
```

Por algo assim:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = pesquisa.GroupBy(x => x.Data_Venda, x => x.Quantidade).ToList();
```

Acredito que essa função irá agrupar as datas de vendas somando as quantidades

Comment: ola amigo como você sugeriu quando eu faço a consulta no GRID. só me mostra a data, ou seja ainda não ta dando certo

Comment: Você tem razão, me desculpe, com o que eu falei ele monta uma lista agrupando o datetime como Key e uma lista de inteiros. Você vai precisar uma uma lista auxiliar para armazenar os valores, fica assim:
`var auxLista = pesquisa.GroupBy(x => x.Data, x => x.Quantidade).ToList();
   var listaProdutos = new List<Produto>();
            foreach (var aux in auxLista)
            {
                listaProdutos.Add(new Produto {Data = aux.Key, Quantidade = aux.Sum()});
            }   `

Comment: Amigo Muito Obrigado pela sua ajuda em soluciona o problema da minha consulta mais o procedimento que você Sugere a sima não deu certo ta dando erro  nessa função Sum

Comment: Putz, mas o seu atributo é do tipo numérico? Senão dá problema mesmo, manda a estrutura da sua classe pra eu dar uma olhada

Comment: o meu Email e ubirailton@outlook.com mada um oi la que eu envio o codigo para voce da uma olhada e alguns prints. da tela